# Aggregates query is too slow with $addField in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Getting too much time to execute aggregates query. I have the collection name `sellerproducts` in this I have `variant` array. I have created `$lookup` with `sellerinventorystocks` collection to find the available stock.

Now I have to create a filter to fetch only those documents which have stock.

In which I am using `$sum` for the total `availableStock` created virtual field in `variant` array.

My Query for `aggregate`:

```json
[{
  "$addFields": {
    "_category_id_": "$category_id"
  }
}, {
  "$addFields": {
    "_variants_": "$variants"
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "sellerinventorystocks",
    "let": {
      "sku": "$variants.sku",
      "seller_id": "$seller_id"
    },
    "pipeline": [{
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [{
            "$in": ["$sku", "$$sku"]
          }, {
            "$eq": ["$$seller_id", "$seller_id"]
          }]
        }
      }
    }],
    "as": "sku_details"
  }
}, {
  "$addFields": {
    "variants": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$variants",
            "as": "variant",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": ["$$variant.status", "active"]
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "row",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$row._id",
          "discount": {
            "$cond": [{
              "$eq": ["$$row.admin_discount", 0]
            }, 0, {
              "$divide": [{
                "$multiply": ["$$row.price", "$$row.admin_discount"]
              }, 100]
            }]
          },
          "discounted_price": {
            "$subtract": ["$$row.price", {
              "$cond": [{
                "$eq": ["$$row.admin_discount", 0]
              }, 0, {
                "$divide": [{
                  "$multiply": ["$$row.price", "$$row.admin_discount"]
                }, 100]
              }]
            }]
          },
          "availableStock": {
            "$sum": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$sku_details",
                "as": "sku_detail",
                "in": {
                  "$cond": [{
                    "$eq": ["$$sku_detail.sku", "$$row.sku"]
                  }, "$$sku_detail.total_stock", 0]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "sell_in_bulk_for": "$$row.sell_in_bulk_for",
          "sellBulkValues": "$$row.sellBulkValues",
          "sellBulkValues_for_b2b": "$$row.sellBulkValues_for_b2b",
          "media": "$$row.media",
          "video_media": "$$row.video_media",
          "mrp_from": "$$row.mrp_from",
          "status": "$$row.status",
          "mrp_to": "$$row.mrp_to",
          "video_url": "$$row.video_url",
          "dimensions": "$$row.dimensions",
          "added_by": "$$row.added_by",
          "dimension_type": "$$row.dimension_type",
          "height": "$$row.height",
          "width": "$$row.width",
          "length": "$$row.length",
          "weight": "$$row.weight",
          "weight_type": "$$row.weight_type",
          "size": "$$row.size",
          "colour": "$$row.colour",
          "size_chart": "$$row.size_chart",
          "size_chart_flag": "$$row.size_chart_flag",
          "other_attribute": "$$row.other_attribute",
          "sku": "$$row.sku",
          "price": "$$row.price",
          "seller_discount_kare": "$$row.seller_discount_kare",
          "discount_to_customer": "$$row.discount_to_customer",
          "admin_discount": "$$row.admin_discount",
          "hsn": "$$row.hsn",
          "gst_tax": "$$row.gst_tax",
          "sell_in_bulk": "$$row.sell_in_bulk",
          "bulk_quantity": "$$row.bulk_quantity",
          "bulk_discount": "$$row.bulk_discount",
          "inventory_and_warehouse": "$$row.inventory_and_warehouse",
          "stock_status": "$$row.stock_status"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "wishlists",
    "let": {
      "product_id": "$_id"
    },
    "as": "wishlist_details",
    "pipeline": [{
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [{
            "$eq": ["$product_id", "$$product_id"]
          }, {
            "$eq": ["$user_id", "6479c0b9366bb273bb456eb8"]
          }]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$limit": 1
    }]
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$wishlist_details",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "sellers",
    "localField": "seller_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "seller_details"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$seller_details",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "seller_details.status": "active"
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "productcategories",
    "localField": "category_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "category_id_"
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "catalogueproducts",
    "let": {
      "product_id": "$_id"
    },
    "pipeline": [{
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$eq": ["$product_id", "$$product_id"]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "catalogues",
        "localField": "catalogue_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "catalogue_details"
      }
    }, {
      "$sort": {
        "catalogue_details.discount": -1
      }
    }, {
      "$limit": 1
    }],
    "as": "catalogue_products"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$catalogue_products",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
}, {
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "productratings",
    "let": {
      "product_id": "$_id"
    },
    "pipeline": [{
      "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [{
            "$eq": ["$product_id", "$$product_id"]
          }]
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$count": "product_rating"
    }],
    "as": "rating_details"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$rating_details",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "seller_id": "$seller_id",
    "product_id": "$product_id",
    "product_name": "$product_name",
    "category_id": "$category_id",
    "sub_category_id": "$sub_category_id",
    "sub_sub_category_id": "$sub_sub_category_id",
    "brand_id": "$brand_id",
    "sell_on_type": "$sell_on_type",
    "fullfilled_by": "$fullfilled_by",
    "return_exchange": "$return_exchange",
    "return_exchange_for": "$return_exchange_for",
    "return_days_for_b2b": "$return_days_for_b2b",
    "delivery_time": "$delivery_time",
    "delivery_time_for_b2b": "$delivery_time_for_b2b",
    "return_days": "$return_days",
    "featured_product": "$featured_product",
    "features": "$features",
    "specification": "$specification",
    "description": "$description",
    "seo_short_description": "$seo_short_description",
    "seo_long_description": "$seo_long_description",
    "slug": "$slug",
    "variants": "$variants",
    "admin_approval": "$admin_approval",
    "faqs": "$faqs",
    "bought_together_products": "$bought_together_products",
    "related_products": "$related_products",
    "disapprove_reason": "$disapprove_reason",
    "status": "$status",
    "average_rating": "$average_rating",
    "deletedAt": "$deletedAt",
    "IsEdit": "$IsEdit",
    "updated_by": "$updated_by",
    "approved_on": "$approved_on",
    "_id": "$_id",
    "updatedAt": "$updatedAt",
    "createdAt": "$createdAt",
    "seller_details": "$seller_details",
    "_category_id_": "$_category_id_",
    "category_details": "$category_id",
    "wishlist_details": "$wishlist_details",
    "sku_details": "$sku_details",
    "total_rating": "$rating_details.product_rating",
    "catalogue_products": "$catalogue_products",
    "_variants_": "$_variants_"
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "admin_approval": "approved",
    "status": "active",
    "deletedAt": false,
    "sell_on_type": {
      "$in": ["b2c", "both"]
    },
    "variants.availableStock": {
      "$ne": 0
    }
  }
}]
```

I have executed the `explain()` and got following result

```
[ { "$cursor" : { "queryPlanner" : { "plannerVersion" : 1.0, "namespace" : "studentkare.sellerproducts", "indexFilterSet" : false, "parsedQuery" : { "$and" : [ { "admin_approval" : { "$eq" : "approved" } }, { "deletedAt" : { "$eq" : false } }, { "status" : { "$eq" : "active" } }, { "sell_on_type" : { "$in" : [ "b2c", "both" ] } } ] }, "queryHash" : "FC39C71D", "planCacheKey" : "915F92B6", "winningPlan" : { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "filter" : { "$and" : [ { "admin_approval" : { "$eq" : "approved" } }, { "sell_on_type" : { "$in" : [ "b2c", "both" ] } }, { "status" : { "$eq" : "active" } } ] }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "deletedAt" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "deletedAt_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "deletedAt" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "deletedAt" : [ "[false, false]" ] } } } }, "rejectedPlans" : [ { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "filter" : { "$and" : [ { "deletedAt" : { "$eq" : false } }, { "sell_on_type" : { "$in" : [ "b2c", "both" ] } }, { "status" : { "$eq" : "active" } } ] }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "admin_approval" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "admin_approval_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "admin_approval" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "admin_approval" : [ "[\"approved\", \"approved\"]" ] } } } }, { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "filter" : { "$and" : [ { "admin_approval" : { "$eq" : "approved" } }, { "deletedAt" : { "$eq" : false } }, { "sell_on_type" : { "$in" : [ "b2c", "both" ] } } ] }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "status" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "status_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "status" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "status" : [ "[\"active\", \"active\"]" ] } } } }, { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "filter" : { "$and" : [ { "admin_approval" : { "$eq" : "approved" } }, { "deletedAt" : { "$eq" : false } }, { "status" : { "$eq" : "active" } } ] }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "sell_on_type" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "sell_on_type_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "sell_on_type" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "sell_on_type" : [ "[\"b2c\", \"b2c\"]", "[\"both\", \"both\"]" ] } } } }, { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "admin_approval" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "admin_approval_1_deletedAt_1_status_1_sell_on_type_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "admin_approval" : [  ], "deletedAt" : [  ], "status" : [  ], "sell_on_type" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "admin_approval" : [ "[\"approved\", \"approved\"]" ], "deletedAt" : [ "[false, false]" ], "status" : [ "[\"active\", \"active\"]" ], "sell_on_type" : [ "[\"b2c\", \"b2c\"]", "[\"both\", \"both\"]" ] } } } }, { "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT", "transformBy" : { "IsEdit" : 1.0, "_category_id_" : 1.0, "_id" : 1.0, "_variants_" : 1.0, "admin_approval" : 1.0, "approved_on" : 1.0, "average_rating" : 1.0, "bought_together_products" : 1.0, "brand_id" : 1.0, "catalogue_products" : 1.0, "category_id" : 1.0, "createdAt" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "delivery_time" : 1.0, "delivery_time_for_b2b" : 1.0, "description" : 1.0, "disapprove_reason" : 1.0, "faqs" : 1.0, "featured_product" : 1.0, "features" : 1.0, "fullfilled_by" : 1.0, "product_id" : 1.0, "product_name" : 1.0, "rating_details.product_rating" : 1.0, "related_products" : 1.0, "return_days" : 1.0, "return_days_for_b2b" : 1.0, "return_exchange" : 1.0, "return_exchange_for" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "seller_details" : 1.0, "seller_id" : 1.0, "seo_long_description" : 1.0, "seo_short_description" : 1.0, "sku_details" : 1.0, "slug" : 1.0, "specification" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "sub_category_id" : 1.0, "sub_sub_category_id" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0, "updated_by" : 1.0, "variants" : 1.0, "wishlist_details" : 1.0 }, "inputStage" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "admin_approval" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "deletedAt" : 1.0, "sell_on_type" : 1.0, "variants.colour" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "Variant indexes", "isMultiKey" : true, "multiKeyPaths" : { "admin_approval" : [  ], "status" : [  ], "deletedAt" : [  ], "sell_on_type" : [  ], "variants.colour" : [ "variants" ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "admin_approval" : [ "[\"approved\", \"approved\"]" ], "status" : [ "[\"active\", \"active\"]" ], "deletedAt" : [ "[false, false]" ], "sell_on_type" : [ "[\"b2c\", \"b2c\"]", "[\"both\", \"both\"]" ], "variants.colour" : [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ] } } } } ] } } }, { "$addFields" : { "_category_id_" : "$category_id" } }, { "$addFields" : { "_variants_" : "$variants" } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "sellerinventorystocks", "as" : "sku_details", "let" : { "sku" : "$variants.sku", "seller_id" : "$seller_id" }, "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$and" : [ { "$in" : [ "$sku", "$$sku" ] }, { "$eq" : [ "$$seller_id", "$seller_id" ] } ] } } } ] } }, { "$addFields" : { "variants" : { "$map" : { "input" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$variants", "as" : "variant", "cond" : { "$eq" : [ "$$variant.status", { "$const" : "active" } ] } } }, "as" : "row", "in" : { "_id" : "$$row._id", "discount" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$row.admin_discount", { "$const" : 0.0 } ] }, { "$const" : 0.0 }, { "$divide" : [ { "$multiply" : [ "$$row.price", "$$row.admin_discount" ] }, { "$const" : 100.0 } ] } ] }, "discounted_price" : { "$subtract" : [ "$$row.price", { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$row.admin_discount", { "$const" : 0.0 } ] }, { "$const" : 0.0 }, { "$divide" : [ { "$multiply" : [ "$$row.price", "$$row.admin_discount" ] }, { "$const" : 100.0 } ] } ] } ] }, "availableStock" : { "$sum" : [ { "$map" : { "input" : "$sku_details", "as" : "sku_detail", "in" : { "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$sku_detail.sku", "$$row.sku" ] }, "$$sku_detail.total_stock", { "$const" : 0.0 } ] } } } ] }, "sell_in_bulk_for" : "$$row.sell_in_bulk_for", "sellBulkValues" : "$$row.sellBulkValues", "sellBulkValues_for_b2b" : "$$row.sellBulkValues_for_b2b", "media" : "$$row.media", "video_media" : "$$row.video_media", "mrp_from" : "$$row.mrp_from", "status" : "$$row.status", "mrp_to" : "$$row.mrp_to", "video_url" : "$$row.video_url", "dimensions" : "$$row.dimensions", "added_by" : "$$row.added_by", "dimension_type" : "$$row.dimension_type", "height" : "$$row.height", "width" : "$$row.width", "length" : "$$row.length", "weight" : "$$row.weight", "weight_type" : "$$row.weight_type", "size" : "$$row.size", "colour" : "$$row.colour", "size_chart" : "$$row.size_chart", "size_chart_flag" : "$$row.size_chart_flag", "other_attribute" : "$$row.other_attribute", "sku" : "$$row.sku", "price" : "$$row.price", "seller_discount_kare" : "$$row.seller_discount_kare", "discount_to_customer" : "$$row.discount_to_customer", "admin_discount" : "$$row.admin_discount", "hsn" : "$$row.hsn", "gst_tax" : "$$row.gst_tax", "sell_in_bulk" : "$$row.sell_in_bulk", "bulk_quantity" : "$$row.bulk_quantity", "bulk_discount" : "$$row.bulk_discount", "inventory_and_warehouse" : "$$row.inventory_and_warehouse", "stock_status" : "$$row.stock_status" } } } } }, { "$match" : { "variants.availableStock" : { "$not" : { "$eq" : 0.0 } } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "wishlists", "as" : "wishlist_details", "let" : { "product_id" : "$_id" }, "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$and" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$product_id", "$$product_id" ] }, { "$eq" : [ "$user_id", "647ad57440a8698c11f27f5b" ] } ] } } }, { "$limit" : 1.0 } ], "unwinding" : { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "sellers", "as" : "seller_details", "localField" : "seller_id", "foreignField" : "_id", "unwinding" : { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true } } }, { "$match" : { "seller_details.status" : { "$eq" : "active" } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "productcategories", "as" : "category_id_", "localField" : "category_id", "foreignField" : "_id" } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "catalogueproducts", "as" : "catalogue_products", "let" : { "product_id" : "$_id" }, "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$eq" : [ "$product_id", "$$product_id" ] } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "catalogues", "localField" : "catalogue_id", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "catalogue_details" } }, { "$sort" : { "catalogue_details.discount" : -1.0 } }, { "$limit" : 1.0 } ], "unwinding" : { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true } } }, { "$lookup" : { "from" : "productratings", "as" : "rating_details", "let" : { "product_id" : "$_id" }, "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$and" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$product_id", "$$product_id" ] } ] } } }, { "$count" : "product_rating" } ], "unwinding" : { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true } } }, { "$project" : { "seller_id" : "$seller_id", "product_id" : "$product_id", "product_name" : "$product_name", "category_id" : "$category_id", "sub_category_id" : "$sub_category_id", "sub_sub_category_id" : "$sub_sub_category_id", "brand_id" : "$brand_id", "sell_on_type" : "$sell_on_type", "fullfilled_by" : "$fullfilled_by", "return_exchange" : "$return_exchange", "return_exchange_for" : "$return_exchange_for", "return_days_for_b2b" : "$return_days_for_b2b", "delivery_time" : "$delivery_time", "delivery_time_for_b2b" : "$delivery_time_for_b2b", "return_days" : "$return_days", "featured_product" : "$featured_product", "features" : "$features", "specification" : "$specification", "description" : "$description", "seo_short_description" : "$seo_short_description", "seo_long_description" : "$seo_long_description", "slug" : "$slug", "variants" : "$variants", "admin_approval" : "$admin_approval", "faqs" : "$faqs", "bought_together_products" : "$bought_together_products", "related_products" : "$related_products", "disapprove_reason" : "$disapprove_reason", "status" : "$status", "average_rating" : "$average_rating", "deletedAt" : "$deletedAt", "IsEdit" : "$IsEdit", "updated_by" : "$updated_by", "approved_on" : "$approved_on", "_id" : "$_id", "updatedAt" : "$updatedAt", "createdAt" : "$createdAt", "seller_details" : "$seller_details", "_category_id_" : "$_category_id_", "category_details" : "$category_id", "wishlist_details" : "$wishlist_details", "sku_details" : "$sku_details", "total_rating" : "$rating_details.product_rating", "catalogue_products" : "$catalogue_products", "_variants_" : "$_variants_" } } ]
```

Where is the mistake that query is getting time?

Comment: Your query has 14 `$lookup`, this looks like a very poor design. Unlike relational RDBMS databases, NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins (some NoSQL databases do not even support joins at all). Typically a NoSQL database has much less collections than you have tables in according relational database like Oracle or MySQL. You may review your design.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Yes made some improvements in my query now it's fast rather than prev.